# How to hide button ''Send Mail' and 'Hold' in sale order page, magento 2

Tags: admin, orders, magento2.2, sales-order

Using magento 2.2, admin page. I need to hide button **'Send Mail'** and **'Hold'** in order page of status **'Pending'**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override 1 file to achieve this.

> Override **`/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View.php`**. Find and comment/remove below code:

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::emails') && !$order->isCanceled()) {
    $message = __('Are you sure you want to send an order email to customer?');
    $this->addButton(
        'send_notification',
        [
            'label' => __('Send Email'),
            'class' => 'send-email',
            'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getEmailUrl()}')"
        ]
    );
}
```

and

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::hold') && $order->canHold()) {
    $this->addButton(
        'order_hold',
        [
            'label' => __('Hold'),
            'class' => __('hold'),
            'id' => 'order-view-hold-button',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'url' => $this->getHoldUrl()
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```

That's done.

Comment: How to override this block?

Comment: @BongChannarith, you can check http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-2-overriding-block-model-controller-magento2/ to know about overriding block.